# How to show Rails ActiveRecord query time in Heroku pry rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activerecord, pry, pry-rails

When I run an ActiveRecord query in my local console, I am shown both how long the query took to run (in ms) and the raw SQL that was generated from my ActiveRecord code. For example:

```rb
$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 92420
Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.3)
[1] pry(main)> TableName.count
   (26336.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "table_names"
=> 10005457
```

But when I run the same query in a Heroku rails console, I don't see the query time or SQL, just the result. Example:

```rb
$ heroku run rails c
Running rails c on ⬢ app-name... up, run.9115 (Free)
Loading production environment (Rails 6.1.3)
[1] pry(main)> TableName.count
=> 10005457
```

If it's relevant, I have `gem 'pry-byebug'` and `gem 'pry-rails'` installed via my Gemfile (*not* in the `development` group). I'm also using PostgreSQL as my database.

Answer (score 2):

Whether to display query time and SQL depends on [Log Levels](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels).

It displays when the log level is `:debug` or corresponding number `0`.

You could check `config.log_level` in `config/environments/production.rb`.

If it's `:debug`, then it might be Heroku has changed log level somehow.

You could check the log level in Hereku console by `Rails.logger.level`.

And set log level to `:debug` by `Rails.logger.level = :debug`.